# Function Calls but element disappears

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to make a simple zodiac webpage that grabs the answer from an array using a function that has a for loop and an if statement, but the answer when I click the button continues to just flash and disappear. How do I keep the answer on the page?
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="header"><h1 class="zodiactitle">Learn your Life's Mysteries w/ the </br>ZODIAC</h1></div>
 <form>
  <input id="zodiac" placeholder="   ENTER YOUR ZODIAC">
  <span class="click"><button class="button" onclick="getZodiac()">Click to find out more</button></span>
</form>

<div class="details">
<h3 id="birthdate"></h3>
<h3 id="zodiacsign"></h3>
</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
function getZodiac(){
  var sign = document.getElementById("zodiac").value;

  for( i = 0; i < zodiacSigns.length; i++){
  //if statement to match correct input to correct zodiac
  if(sign == zodiacSigns[i].sign){
    document.getElementById("birthdate").innerHTML = zodiacSigns[i].birthdate;
    document.getElementById("zodiacsign").innerHTML = zodiacSigns[i].zodiac;
    return;

   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code? At least the elements "birthdate" and "zodiacsign" please.

Comment: Where is `getZodiac()` being called? Are a `<form>` and submit button involved? If so, the form may be navigating to its `action` or at least refreshing the current page. [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Is this python? Where are semicolons!

Comment: @MehulMohan Though commonly used, [they aren't actually required in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

Comment: @Jonathan but I'll consider it as an extremely bad practice and a source of so many unknown bugs. Try to use semicolons if possible.

Comment: Your question has no clue about the variable `zodiacSigns`. Where does it come from?

Comment: @MehulMohan In general, I tend to use semicolons as well, but they're absence isn't an outright fault. See "[An Open Letter to JavaScript Leaders Regarding Semicolons](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)" Also, [StandardJS](http://standardjs.com/).

Comment: @Jonathan great article. Thanks.

Comment: I will start  using semicolons now for best practices. I put up the html. Thanks guys for the input. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think the problem is that when you click the button, your form is being submitted and your page flashes. You can add [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to fix it. I made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dawchihliou/gL9ocL3y/) for more clarity.

```
function getZodiac(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // the rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: It works for your code, but not mine. I added it and yet the function still only blinks the answer instead of having it stay.

Comment: have you added the `e` as your parameter of the function?

Comment: Can you try adding event listener the way in the demo and take away `onClick="getZodiac()"` in your html.